# Find D using N (factorizing)

Tags: algorithm, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to find D by factorizing N.

My `N is 265291078722948385089717069136983657793`

I've found P & Q using

```
 n = p.q 

P - 14716976826788780483 
Q -18026193955816294571
```

Similarly I've found  ɸ using

```
ɸ = (p - 1).(q - 1)
```

Next step says

```
Select e; such that, e is relatively prime to ɸ and e < ɸ, gcd (e, ɸ) = 1
```

Now I am stuck at this step and I'm unable to proceed through. Im not sure if this is the right way to factorize N to find D or not.

P.S - Last step is `Select d; such that, d.e mod ɸ = 1 or e = 1 mod ɸ` 
using this step I'm supposed to find D. But I"m stuck at second last step.

Any help is appreciated. :)

EDIT (ANSWER) : 
E =65537 (2^16 + 1), it is the most common form for encryption and is used widely.

```
The query boils down to 
D*E mod ɸ = 1
which implies that D*E = Xɸ + 1, where X=1,2,3,4....
D = (Xɸ + 1)/E
```

now simply use the above logic to obtain the possible values for D :)

Comment: I think you can just select an `e`. For example `5`. And then calculate `d` from that.

Comment: you mean to say E could be arbitrarily any prime number ?

Comment: it still needs to be co-prime with \phi. If `5` does not fit, try `7` and so on.

Comment: Wikipedia says: "e having a short bit-length and small Hamming weight results in more efficient encryption – most commonly 2^16 + 1 = 65,537. However, much smaller values of e (such as 3) have been shown to be less secure in some settings" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Key_generation

Comment: I understand the fact that e can be between 3 to 65537. and is usually taken as 65537 but when e is taken as that. I get the incorrect answer :/

Comment: why do you get the incorrect answer?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The tuple (e, N) comprises the RSA public key. In what scenario do you have access to N, but not its factorization, and not e? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It was quiz question last year in one of my friend's exam. He faced the same question in interview. That's why Im keen into it

Comment: It's more of deriving D by factoring N.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. It might be better suited for [crypto.se] or [math.se], but check their help center first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with e=3, then try e=5, 7, 11 and so on. 
The condition to satisfy is

```
(d * e) % φ(n) = 1
```

In your example φ(n) = 265291078722948385056973898354378582740

So, in order to find d, I would make a table

```
For e=3, d = (φ(n)+1) / e
           =  265291078722948385056973898354378582741 / 3
           = 88430359574316128352324632784792860913
```

Now find for e=5, 7 and so on

Comment: This tool is very handy to verify your calculations 

"RSA-Tool 2 / Cryptography Tools / Downloads - Tuts 4 You"
https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.455

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to guess `e`, because it is the *public exponent*, it should be out there in the public along with `n` in the public key `(e, n)` pair. Otherwise you have half key, any number co-prime to `ɸ(n)`, `gcd(e, ɸ(n)) = 1` is a candidate public exponent.

After you factorized the modulo `n`, you pretty much done. Just take the public exponent `e` and find the [multiplicative modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `e (mod ɸ(n))`, i.e `d . e ≡ 1 (mod ɸ(n))`. You must get `d` because `e` and `ɸ(n)` must be co-primes to get an inverse.